# app submission: Bundle ID and Bundle ID suffix

Tags: ios, bundle, identifier, submission

I have looked at other answers here on stackOverflow but they do not give enough details.
I am in the process of submitting an application to the app store and i am being asked for a bundle id. There is one already on the list. Should I create another one or not?
It is also asking for a bundle id suffix: it says it should match the one in my info.plist: is there a bundle id suffix in my info.plist already or i need to create one?

Answer (score 0):

The bundle ID should match the one in your info.plist, and is usually reverse DNS format (for example, com.yourcompany.yourappname).  I've never heard of a bundle ID suffix, though.